# jQuery AJAX call doesnt work on server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

i have a jQuery AJAX webmethod in ASP.Net that works perfectly fine when tested locally. but when uploaded to the server, sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. when i debugged the code with firebug i see the the webmethod gets called but jumps right away to the error section of the ajax script.
thats my second week of research and i still couldnt find anything to help me.

**jQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //get current date
        var _currdate = new Date();
        var currday = _currdate.getDate();
        var currmonth = _currdate.getMonth() + 1;
        var curryear = _currdate.getFullYear();
        var currdate = curryear + "-" + currmonth + "-" + currday;

        //on page load event, check to see if employees are added to the schedule
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Schedule.aspx/GetSchedule",
            data: '{"FinancialDate" : "' + currdate + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#timepanel').append(data.d);
                $('.schslider').each(function () {
                    //check employee checkboxes if schedule exists
                    if ($('.schslider').length > 0) {
                        $('input#chk' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('checked', true);
                        $('input:checkbox:checked').parent('label').addClass('selected');
                        empcount = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
                        $('#emplistddl').text("Liste d'employés (" + empcount + " Employés Selectionnés) | Employees' List (" + empcount + " Selected Employees)");
                    }
                    //get the values for the slider
                    var startvalue = $('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'start').text();
                    var endvalue = $('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'end').text();
                    startvalue = (parseInt(startvalue.substring(0, 2), 10) * 60) + parseInt(startvalue.substring(3), 10);
                    endvalue = (parseInt(endvalue.substring(0, 2), 10) * 60) + parseInt(endvalue.substring(3), 10);
                    $('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'start').remove();
                    $('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'end').remove();
                    $(this).slider({
                        range: true,
                        min: 480,
                        max: 1380,
                        values: [startvalue, endvalue],
                        step: 5,
                        slide: function (event, ui) {
                            var minutes0 = parseInt(ui.values[0] % 60);
                            var hours0 = parseInt(ui.values[0] / 60 % 24);
                            var minutes1 = parseInt(ui.values[1] % 60);
                            var hours1 = parseInt(ui.values[1] / 60 % 24);
                            var time = getTime(hours0, minutes0) + ' - ' + getTime(hours1, minutes1);
                            $(this).parent('div').children('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'timestamp').text(time);
                            var total = parseFloat((hours1 + (minutes1 / 60)) - (hours0 + (minutes0 / 60)));
                            $(this).parent('div').children('span#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'total').text(total.toFixed(2) + ' hrs');
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (e) { $('#loaderrorboxtimepanel').removeClass('hidebox').addClass('showbox'); }
        });
</script>
```

**the webmethod code is below:**

```
<WebMethod(True)> _
    Public Shared Function GetSchedule(ByVal FinancialDate As String) As String
        Dim StoreNumber_ForWebMethod As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StoreNumberKey")
        Dim _SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=INTRIS;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=sa;Password=*****")
        Dim _SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select h.magasin, h.employe, e.nom, h.datefinancier, h.debut, h.fin, h.totalheure, h.annee, h.semaine, h.evenement, h.etat, h.breakstart, h.breakend " _
                                                & "from web.dbo.hours h , web.dbo.employee e " _
                                                & "where h.employe = e.numero and h.magasin = " & StoreNumber_ForWebMethod & " and h.datefinancier = '" & FinancialDate & "'", _SqlConnection)
        Dim _DataSet As New DataSet
        Dim ScheduleBuilder As String = Nothing

        _SqlDataAdapter.Fill(_DataSet, "Schedule")

        If Not _SqlDataAdapter Is Nothing Then
            If _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows.Count - 1
                    ScheduleBuilder += "<div id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "timecontainer' class='timecontainer'>" _
                                    & "<span id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "start'>" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("debut").ToString & "</span>" _
                                    & "<span id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "end'>" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("fin").ToString & "</span>" _
                                    & "<label>" & StrConv(_DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("nom").ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase) & "</label>" _
                                    & "<span id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "timestamp' class='timestamp'>" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("debut").ToString & " - " & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("fin").ToString & "</span>" _
                                    & "<span id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "total' class='total'>" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("TotalHeure").ToString & " hrs</span>" _
                                    & "<div id='" & _DataSet.Tables("Schedule").Rows(i).Item("employe").ToString & "' class='schslider'></div></div>"
                Next
            End If
        End If

        Return ScheduleBuilder
    End Function
```

any help would be much appreciated

**Update**
is JSON and webmethods compatible with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @geek: Im using pagemethod since its an intranet

Comment: @embo: i dont get what you mean by this?

Comment: Put the following as your error function in the ajax call and see what it says: function(x,s,m) { alert(m); }

Comment: @patmortech: it says: Internal Server Error.

the thing is, sometimes it loads the schedule and sometimes it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

first i would like to thank @patmortech for guiding me in the right direction by showing me what was the error.
once i found out that, used firebug on firefox to debug the problem and it was a single quote missing for

```
Dim _SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select h.magasin, h.employe, e.nom, h.datefinancier, h.debut, h.fin, h.totalheure, h.annee, h.semaine, h.evenement, h.etat, h.breakstart, h.breakend " _
                                            & "from web.dbo.hours h , web.dbo.employee e " _
                                            & "where h.employe = e.numero and h.magasin = **'" & StoreNumber_ForWebMethod & "'** and h.datefinancier = '" & FinancialDate & "'", _SqlConnection)
```

because it is a string.

problem solved :)

Comment: one more reason to use parameterized queries